# Chrome not asking for proxy password

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, passwords, authentication, password-management

I told Chrome not to save my proxy password, thinking that, this way, it would ask me for the password every time I launch it, but this is not happening. How can Google Chrome authenticate me even if it didn't save my proxy password?

Comment: @Ramhound no, no authentication asked by any browser...

Comment: @Ramhound no, because I told the other browsers to store my proxy password

Comment: @Ramhound why do you say I am not willing to help? I am trying to understand what's happening like yourself and I've been replying to all your questions. Anyway, thanks for your help and for the downvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the proxy server being used, some can store 'sessions' that rely on the MAC address used to authenticate - so when the same mac address is requesting access it is already in the cache of authenticated users.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the explanation, I wouldn't be able to explain it otherwise :)